# Why does my llvm function jit-evaluate to 0?

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

I am playing with llvm (and antlr), working vaguely along the lines of the Kaleidoscope tutorial. I successfully created LLVM-IR code from basic arithmetic expressions both on top-level and as function definitions, which corresponds to the tutorial chapters up to 3.

Now I would like to incrementally add JIT support, starting with the top-level arithmetic expressions.  Here is my problem:

- Basic comparison makes it seem as if I follow the same sequence of function calls as the tutorial, only with a simpler code organization
- The generated IR code looks good
- The function definition is apparently found, since otherwise the code would exit (i verified this by intentionally looking for a wrongly spelled function name)
- **However the call of the function pointer created by JIT evaluation always returns zero.**

These snippets (excerpt) are executed as part of the antlr visitor of the main/entry-node of my grammar:

```
  //Top node main -- top level expression
  antlrcpp::Any visitMain(ExprParser::MainContext *ctx)  
  {
    llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();
    llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
    llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();
    TheJIT = ExitOnErr( llvm::orc::KaleidoscopeJIT::Create() );

    InitializeModuleAndPassManager();
    
    // ... Code which visits the child nodes  ...

  }
```

`InitializeModuleAndPassManager()` is the same as in the tutorial:

```
static void InitializeModuleAndPassManager() 
{
  // Open a new context and module.
  TheContext = std::make_unique<llvm::LLVMContext>();
  TheModule = std::make_unique<llvm::Module>("commandline", *TheContext);
  TheModule->setDataLayout(TheJIT->getDataLayout());
  // Create a new builder for the module.
  Builder = std::make_unique<llvm::IRBuilder<>>(*TheContext);
  // Create a new pass manager attached to it.
  TheFPM = std::make_unique<llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager>(TheModule.get());
  // Do simple "peephole" optimizations and bit-twiddling optzns.
  TheFPM->add(llvm::createInstructionCombiningPass());
  // Reassociate expressions.
  TheFPM->add(llvm::createReassociatePass());
  // Eliminate Common SubExpressions.
  TheFPM->add(llvm::createGVNPass());
  // Simplify the control flow graph (deleting unreachable blocks, etc).
  TheFPM->add(llvm::createCFGSimplificationPass());
  TheFPM->doInitialization();
}
```

This is the function which handles the top-level expression and which is also supposed to do JIT evaluation:

```
//Bare expression without function definition -- create anonymous function
  antlrcpp::Any visitBareExpr(ExprParser::BareExprContext *ctx)
  {
    string fName = "__anon_expr";
    llvm::FunctionType  *FT = llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(*TheContext), false);
    llvm::Function      *F  = llvm::Function::Create(FT, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, fName, TheModule.get());
    llvm::BasicBlock    *BB = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(*TheContext, "entry", F);
    Builder->SetInsertPoint(BB);
    llvm::Value* Expression=visit(ctx->expr()).as<llvm::Value* >();
    Builder->CreateRet(Expression);
    llvm::verifyFunction(*F);   
    //TheFPM->run(*F);//outcommented this because i wanted to try JIT before optimization- 
    //it causes a compile error right now because i probably lack some related code.
    //However i do not assume that a missing optimization run will cause the problem that i have
    F->print(llvm::errs());
    // Create a ResourceTracker to track JIT'd memory allocated to our
    // anonymous expression -- that way we can free it after executing.
    auto RT = TheJIT->getMainJITDylib().createResourceTracker();
    auto TSM = llvm::orc::ThreadSafeModule(move(TheModule), move(TheContext));
    ExitOnErr(TheJIT->addModule(move(TSM), RT));
    InitializeModuleAndPassManager();
    // Search the JIT for the __anon_expr symbol.
    auto ExprSymbol = ExitOnErr(TheJIT->lookup("__anon_expr"));
    // Get the symbol's address and cast it to the right type (takes no
    // arguments, returns a double) so we can call it as a native function.
    double (*FP)() = (double (*)())(intptr_t)ExprSymbol.getAddress();
    double ret = FP();
    fprintf(stderr, "Evaluated to %f\n", ret);
    // Delete the anonymous expression module from the JIT.
    ExitOnErr(RT->remove());
    return F;
  }
```

Now this is what happens as an example:

```
[robert@robert-ux330uak test4_expr_llvm_2]$ ./testmain '3*4'
define double @__anon_expr() {
entry:
  ret float 1.200000e+01
}
Evaluated to 0.000000
```

I would be thankful for any ideas about what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: The returned value doesn't match the return type of the function. It should be `ret double 1.200000e+01`.

Comment: BTW, running `llvm::verifyFunction` is a good idea to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks - indeed the problem can be traced back to sloppyness concerning float vs double datatypes. My "atomic expression" visitor was using "stof()"instead of "stod()" to parse the literal.  However i did call "verifyFunction" above and I am surprised that this error did not pop up earlyer on...

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you called it. The problem is that you're ignoring the return value of `verifyFunction`.  You can also pass in a stream to print its output to, for example `&llvm::dbgs()`.